# How to force cache cleared when user open website PHP

Tags: php, browser-cache

I have updated some changes in my website but changes only displays when browser cache cleared, there are more than 2000 users use this website daily basis , how can i force cache cleared when they open website.

I have few example but I am not aware these will work or not like given below.

```
<?php
header("Expires: Tue, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT");
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
?>

AND 
clearstatcache(); function
```

Comment: Just for clarification you don't really clear the browser cache you just tell the browser to not cache the page. This is a little different. The cached page could be still loaded because it is still there.

Comment: @Aaron can't we force browser to clear cache before loading specific website

Comment: So you don't want to cache .js or .css files? or are there other types as well ?

Comment: @ElenaRoman I just want when user will open this website after 10th May 2019, it must displays all the data from server not from cache , only css changes made

Comment: I suggest to use javascript for that task. I don't know any PHP Function that works like that since it is server-side. You can try: location.reload(true); Cache.key() and Cache.delete()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where you have the css link just add a param to end of the url like this

The browser caches resources based on url and since we are changing the url by adding ?version=1 it will download the new css.

To avoid this issue in the future, when you deploy any css/js changes to production have a script that changes the name of the css file using this pattern style_timestamp.css
style_1557467134.css